# Why are each frame not equally length?

Tags: python, python-2.7, audio, librosa

I am currently sampling and framing some audio files, such that I can provide it as an input for an neural network.  I am using [Librosa](https://github.com/librosa/librosa) to sample the audio and frame it, especially the framing is very important, as this is being fed as a input for a neural network need which means that the length has to be consistent, which seem to be problem with my current. frames.

I am currently sampling and framing like this:

```
def load_sound_files(file_paths , data_input):
    raw_sounds = []
    data_output = []
    for fp in file_paths:
        y,sr = librosa.load(fp)
        X = librosa.util.frame(y)
        raw_sounds.append(X)
return raw_sounds
```

Each audio file in appended to a list, and for each entry in the list is there an array with each frame. So information in raw_sounds are stored like this:

```
[array([[frame],[frame],...,[frame]],dtype=float32), ...]
```

I seem to have a problem with different sized frames, each audio files has different length, but since i frame it with the same setting should each frame be the same, but that is not case according these print debugs.

```
print len(raw_sounds)
print len(raw_sounds[0])
print len(raw_sounds[0][0])
print len(raw_sounds[0][1])
print '\n'
print len(raw_sounds[1])
print len(raw_sounds[1][0])
print len(raw_sounds[1][1])
```

which outputs:

```
270
2048
121
121


96
96
```

Am I setting it up incorrectly? or am I doing something wrong here?

Raw sample:

```
[array([[ -1.58969939e-04,   2.85098387e-04,   2.57675620e-05,
          5.58408792e-04,   2.09050399e-04,   3.10504751e-04,
          7.08066545e-06,   6.51864902e-05,   4.64069366e-04,
         -1.03915379e-04,  -2.09252365e-04,   9.58807232e-06,
         -3.70743481e-04,  -2.73781188e-04,   1.47478888e-03,
         -1.24523379e-02,  -1.38171474e-02,   1.42919633e-03,
          2.60417676e-03,  -9.49124712e-03,   1.84055939e-02,
          5.30609104e-04,  -2.02661729e-03,  -1.09214883e-03,
         -2.67810683e-04,  -9.33001807e-04,   1.57146193e-02,
          3.06987576e-02,  -2.89204344e-02,   8.31141882e-03,
         -5.22559392e-04,   9.57424170e-04,  -1.39959985e-02,
         -2.45519826e-04,   7.94889964e-03,  -2.45057382e-02,
          2.76992898e-02,   2.75033060e-03,   1.91110268e-03,
          2.65958859e-03,   4.22360376e-04,   2.87338579e-03,
          3.60440137e-03,  -6.81304885e-03,   1.19333845e-02,
          5.27647883e-03,  -8.81725773e-02,  -1.10511519e-02,
          1.67427063e-02,   4.18979749e-02,  -1.76561251e-02,
          1.40228057e-02,  -6.56250417e-02,   8.04386102e-04,
          6.77016005e-03,   8.95334259e-02,  -3.07568144e-02,
         -5.68932574e-03,   2.80798669e-03,  -1.94037147e-03,
         -6.80876488e-04,  -7.51503045e-04,   1.61860569e-03,
         -8.96663638e-04,   1.05839630e-03,   4.16457013e-04,
         -1.14849303e-03,   2.51941121e-04,   1.09347668e-04,
         -9.77083837e-05,  -9.70639754e-04,   1.23860082e-03,
         -5.82281128e-03,  -7.96582922e-03,   1.05014764e-01,
          8.55111331e-03,   1.02730282e-02,  -1.64158875e-03,
         -9.96976532e-03,  -1.54927105e-03,  -1.33159547e-03,
          2.07886100e-03,  -9.63974337e-04,   1.92957837e-03,
         -9.57471970e-03,   8.37739408e-02,  -2.46925298e-02,
          1.15760174e-02,   1.53850103e-02,   1.39159057e-02,
          7.28045590e-04,   1.28218243e-02,   2.47708824e-03,
          3.64710722e-05,   2.31177593e-03,  -3.88215925e-03,
          2.85943900e-03,   3.40921571e-03,   8.19356064e-04,
          1.31994265e-03,  -4.02768754e-04,  -3.73146904e-04,
         -2.45199517e-05,  -1.40402978e-03,  -4.53661755e-03,
         -8.06837995e-03,  -3.07087135e-03,   5.65649476e-04,
          8.99529332e-05,   9.43572959e-04,   1.52094246e-04,
         -9.59860045e-04,   2.72397720e-03,   1.27405506e-02,
         -9.37244575e-03,  -1.79420076e-02,   1.07235732e-02,
          2.84450967e-03,   4.49513178e-03,   2.41923026e-05,
         -3.13379533e-05],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [librosa's documentation](http://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.util.frame.html#librosa-util-frame) this is what the `util.frame()` returns:

```
Returns:    
    y_frames : np.ndarray [shape=(frame_length, N_FRAMES)]
    An array of frames sampled from y: y_frames[i, j] == y[j * hop_length + i]
```

So what you get is a two dimensional array. So `raw_sounds[0]` is the first sound file you loaded, and it can be addressed in two dimensions. You should instead use shape to get its size:

```
print raw_sounds[0].shape
```

To get one frame use this notation `result[0][:, nf]` where `nf` is the number of the frame.

The number you are getting when you ask for `raw_sounds[0][0]` is the number of frames, and it will depend on the sound samples size. So it seems to work correctly.

Comment: I am sure if we've misunderstood each other.. I seeking is the length of each frame, and not the number of frames in each sampled audio file.

Comment: to get the length of each frame you can use `raw_sounds[n].shape[0]` for the `n`th sound file.

Comment: I just tried that.. It returns 2048.  which compared with manual counting is print function outputing an incorrect result.  I added the raw data.. How do i make it output 118.. 
Manually counted..   (3 rows * 39 columns + 1 element) = 118.

Comment: 2048 sounds correct since it is the default size, see the default parameters in the documentation, see http://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.util.frame.html#librosa-util-frame. You can change the length by changing the `frame_length` parameter of `util.frame(...)`. Remember that the frames overlap, so samples will reoccur in consecutive frames.

Comment: "Remember that the frames overlap, so samples will reoccur in consecutive frames. " I need each frame to be 25 ms long and there should be a framw shift of 10 ms. which means that if the audio was sampled with 16 khz should there be 400 samples in each frame. I am not sure I understand why the frames are interlapping as you suggest? Is it due to the large frame size? How do i ensure that each frame would contain only the information i need..  I guess this question is getting out of scope now.

Comment: Yes, I think it will be hard to explain it here in the comments :) But I would advice you to look into some literature or examples on digital signal/audio processing. Using overlapping windows/frames is a very common technique, and explaining it would involve quite some math using Fourier transforms and similar.